# Why is “For all the simple things you have done to me, there exists one thing that makes me happy” FALSE? Use nested quantifiers to prove your point

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I've done my due dilligence and tried to answer this question using every resource I could get. KhanAcademy, NesoAcademy, and Rosen's Discrete Mathematics book. I still can't wrap my head around it. Here is how I answered it:

Let x be things you did to me.

Let y be you making me happy.

Let P(x,y) be the thing you did to me that made me happy.

∀x∃!yP(x,y)

According to Rosen (p. 62), the statement with the form ∀x∃yP(x,y) is false when “there is an x such that P(x,y) is false for every y.” Since “there exists one thing that makes me happy,” there is all minus one thing that did not “make me happy.” Therefore, the statement is FALSE because there is an x (a thing you did to me) such that P(x,y) is false (you did not make me happy) for every y (the thing(s) you did to me that make me happy).”

Is this right?

Comment: If you ever did one thing to me that makes me unhappy, then of course both ∀x∃yP(x,y) and ∀x∃!yP(x,y) are false (the latter sentence just additionally means there exists a unique y). To make sense of your sentence above, sine y is quantified thus it has to be interpreted as a quantified happiness which is a little weird here...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in [math.se].

Comment: It doesn't seem necessarily false to me or necessarily true. Needs an additional assumption.